# Number of columns for result set error in SQL database for Java app

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

I'm having an issue with adding data to a sql database through Java on Netbeans.

```
String bladeSerial;
String bladeType;
LocalTime startTime1;

private void startButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    Connection conn = null; 
    Statement st = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db01", "Administrator", "admin"); //run procedure getConnection to connect to the database - see below
        st = conn.createStatement(); //set up a statement st to enable you to send SQL statements to the database.
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println ("Successful Connection");


    String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values ('+bladeSerial+', '+itemText+', '+(String.valueOf(startTime1))+')";
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
        pstmt.setString(2, bladeType);
        pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(startTime1));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I get the error `The column position '1' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'.`

In the database, Serial is `VARCHAR(5)`, Bladetype is `VARCHAR(80)`and StartT1 is `VARCHAR(12)`

The startTime1 variable is saved in the format HH:mm:ss.SSS.

[image: The database structure]

I appreciate any help on this error

Comment: You don't seem to understand how prepared statements work. The query should be `insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values (?, ?, ?)`. The question marks are placeholders for parameters. Concatenating the parameter values in the query completely defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give placeholder in your query. Change your code as given here...

```
String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
pstmt.setString(2, bladeType);
pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(startTime1));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give column names in query when you are using Prepared statement. Do the following changes:

```
 String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values (?, ?, ?)";
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are forming query like simple statement and used it in prepared statement which is not possible, so change your query with place holder like below.

```
String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
pstmt.setString(2, bladeType);
pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(startTime1));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly use variables names like `bladeSerial`, then you should use these String variables as if you're adding multiple Strings.

```
String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values ("+bladeSerial+", "+itemText+", "+(String.valueOf(startTime1))+")";
```

**But this is strictly not recommended as it would introduce serious security issues.**

The recommended way is to use `PreparedStatement`. The query you've written is correct, it's just that you have to use placeholders instead of variable names.

```
String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values (?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
    pstmt.setString(2, bladeType);
    pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(startTime1));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Exception handling
    Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```